# How to refer the JS files from /_layouts/15 folder to C# Class file programmatically

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development, custom, layouts

I placed the custom JavaScript files to /_layouts/15 folder. I tried to refer these scripts to my page by using below c# code. But it is not rendering on the page. Anyone look on this.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(GetType(), "dd", @"/_layouts/15/MultipleDragDropAttachment/DragDrop.js");
```

Answer (score 0):

RegisterClientScriptInclude should have a valid url, it's missing http://sitename
Try
SPContext.Current.Site.Url + "/_layouts/15/MultipleDragDropAttachment/DragDrop.js"

If it is an application page add it in the aspx 
src="/_layouts/15/MultipleDragDropAttachment/DragDrop.js"